# Join Dates Between

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following tables and I want to make the query which can give the result 5(as show in bold below).

I tried to make query however it's not wokring could you please help?

```
 SELECT utl_reader_route.reader_route_code, 
       utl_reader_route_date.read_date 
FROM   utl_reader_route_date 
       JOIN utl_reader_route 
         ON utl_reader_route.reader_route_id = 
            utl_reader_route_date.reader_route_id 
       JOIN utl_meter_reader 
         ON utl_reader_route.meter_reader_id = utl_meter_reader.meter_reader_id 
WHERE  utl_meter_reader.meter_reader_code = 'ADR MRS' 
       AND utl_reader_route_date.read_date BETWEEN '2014-05-01' AND '2014-05-31' 
ORDER  BY read_date
```

*utl_meter_reader*

meter_reader_id .........   meter_reader_code

1   .........ADR MRS

2   .........AGC

*utl_reader_route*

reader_route_id ..........  meter_reader_id

1.........  1

2.........  2

*utl_reader_route_date*

reader_route_date_id.........   reader_route_id.........    read_date

1.........  1.........  20/04/2014

1.........  2.........  20/05/2014

1.........  3.........  20/06/2014

2.........  4.........  20/04/2014

**2.........    5.........**

2.........  6.........  20/06/2014

3.........  7.........  20/04/2014

3.........  8.........  20/05/2014

3.........  9.........  20/06/2014

Comment: Given your sample data, I can't see how you can expect that row from _utl-reader-route-date_ to join to _utl-meter-reader_ since reader-route-id=5 has no match in _utl-meter-reader_ (in the sample). You'd need a LEFT JOIN at the least. (And technically, we don't even know if the date value is null; we don't know its data type since you haven't provided definitions. It could simply be blank.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you need record which has no date . You can put in Or clause and check for null date like

```
select utl_reader_route.reader_route_code,utl_reader_route_date.read_date from 
utl_reader_route_date join utl_reader_route on  
utl_reader_route.reader_route_id=utl_reader_route_date.reader_route_id Join 
utl_meter_reader on utl_reader_route.meter_reader_id=utl_meter_reader.meter_reader_id      where 

utl_meter_reader.meter_reader_code='ADR MRS' and utl_reader_route_date.read_date between '2014-05-01' and '2014-05-31' Or utl_reader_route_date.read_date is Null order by read_date
```

Comment: It didn't make any difference, I am still not getting null fields, Can we please do anything else here

Comment: @user3474932 what do you store in date column.. Null or blank?

Comment: Sorry I am very new in SQL as per understanding Null & blank is same. As we have already tried with Null, could you please let me know how to find blank field please

Comment: @user3474932 just change condition  to Or utl_reader_route_date.read_date is ''

Comment: @user3474932 can you try to remove date condition and try to retrieve blank values and see if you get that record